# How to set appropriate indentation for enumitem with custom labels?

Tags: enumitem

I've used `enumitem` to get my lists more aligned with the text:

[image]

However, I'd like the labels to be "Step 1." etc. When I add this, the labels reach into the margin:

[image]

I understand that I could manually add an appropriate `leftmargin`, but is there a more "proper" way of doing this that does not require estimating the distance, and would work even if I changed from "Step" to another word?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt, parsep=\parskip, partopsep=0pt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}[label=Step \arabic*.]
\item Initialization.
\item Update. This step contains a long descriptions which covers approximately several lines, a little like this example text. 
\item Iterate.
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[2-7]
\end{document}
```

(I've also got the issue that the first paragraph after the list is not indentend, but I guess that's a separate question.)

Comment: For the no identation of the paragraph following the list, just add a empty line after the ````\end{enumitem}```` command.

Comment: Thank you @Patricio!

Comment: Try option `leftmargin=*,labelindent=\parindent`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tom, that worked!